# Turn MySQL results into link then redirecting to next page with POST

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, get

I am trying to turn my database results (users) into clickable links that will then display more information on the select user. Right now I am using $_GET, but the userID will be displayed in the address bar. Is there a way I can POST it instead?

Currently, I have:

```
//fetch and display the results in table
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  $name = $row["name"];
  $id = $row["id"];

//prepare user for GET statement  
echo ' <div><a href=mylink.php?id="'.htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'">'.$row['name'].'</a></div> ';}
```

this displays: www.mylink.php?=id"12345"

I don't want to display the ID. So is the best approach to correct this this? Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `POST`? You can also try using Ajax.

Comment: imho, it should be OK to display the id.

Comment: you could make a unique random string and store that in a table, similar to how a URL shortener works.  But as ihsan said, displaying the id is very common and not typically a topic of concern for most.

Comment: The possible/potential issue with using a `GET` method is, if inputs/variables are not properly sanitized against injection, then it could be problematic.

Comment: What is your concern with showing id? Security? Esthetics?

Comment: My concern is that displaying the ID is that one user can see another user's record if the id is known. I just see it as possible security issue, even with proper sanitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a form and a script to post your data. Something like this:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  $name = $row["name"];
  $id = $row["id"];

//prepare user for GET statement  
echo "<div><a href=\"#\" onclick='javascript:postIt(".htmlspecialchars($row['id']).");'>".$row['name']."</a></div> ";
}

?>
<script>
 function postIt(value){
   document.forms[0].id.value = value;
   document.forms[0].submit();
 }
</script>
<form name="blah" action="mylink.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id">
</form>
```

Comment: it is on `onclick` at the `<a` tag `document.forms[0].submit();` call

Comment: Ahhh I get it. So does this mean I can retrieve the POST value on the next page using $_POST[id]?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all your hyperlinks with little forms:

```
<form action='mylink.php' method=post>
  <input type=hidden value='$id'>
  <input class='post_link' type=submit value='$name'>
</form>
```

CSS would help you to restyle buttons like links:

```
.post_link {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px blue;
    color: blue;
    display: inline;
    height: ...;
    etc
}
```

Open new tab will not work again, and you will see nothing is status bar on hover.

Comment: To open in a new window just add to the form:  `target="_blank"`

Comment: @SergeSeredenko It's not correct syntax. It may work for some browsers, but some will actually reject it without the quotes around `post`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Who told you that? Html doesn't force to quote attributes unless there're some special chars like spaces, quotes etc.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Believe me, I've seen it happen before, which is why I always use quotes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I prefer not to quote attributes, which have predefined possible values, so that IDEs wouldn't highlight them as strings: it helps to see what attributes actually hold my data and which are just markup. And I bet you can't find a browser which a) isn't older than 5 years, c) won't work with method=post in html, d) is used by more than 100k people on Earth. =)

Comment: @SergeSeredenko I'll agree with you to 99% - However the fact that some still use older browsers, not having quotes around it will in fact cause havoc. This is in "my" experiences. Yet you are right though, to a certain extent, I'll give you that.